# Using Enterprise Library Caching Application Block in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, enterprise-library, caching-application-block

I have downloaded the patterns & practices [Silverlight Integration Pack](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight&referringTitle=Home) to use caching (Caching Application Block) in my Silverlight Application, but i tried and tried and didn't get it to work.
I did not find any useful example - does anyone have an example? Just a few lines of code that are showing a simple usage? 
Do I need to use unity?

THANKS!

I used a default configuration that i got from the Enterprise Library Configuration - Tool which i exported as XAML:

```
<el:CachingSettings DefaultCache="In-Memory Cache" x:Key="cachingSilverlightConfiguration">
  <el:CachingSettings.Caches>
    <el:InMemoryCacheData ExpirationPollingInterval="00:02:00" Name="In-Memory Cache" />
  </el:CachingSettings.Caches>
</el:CachingSettings>
```

And when I try to access it with the following code:

```
ObjectCache cache = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ObjectCache>("In-Memory Cache");
```

then, i get an Exception:

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ...
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you did try and the configuration settings, that will help?

Comment: I have added some code to my post that I tried to use. But I am not sure if the code is correct at all, as I couldn't find a uesful example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Randy Levy](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/randylevy) from the Entlib Support, I got [the answer I needed, there](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/276540):

It looks like you haven't configured the container.  If you don't want to call to the server to retrieve the configuration then you need to embed and load the configuration.

```
string stringWithXAMLConfiguration = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<el:ConfigurationDictionary xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" 
                xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" 
                xmlns:el=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2011/entlib"">
<el:CachingSettings DefaultCache=""In-Memory Cache"" x:Key=""cachingSilverlightConfiguration"">
    <el:CachingSettings.Caches>
        <el:InMemoryCacheData ExpirationPollingInterval=""00:02:00"" Name=""In-Memory Cache"" />
        <el:IsolatedStorageCacheData MaxSizeInKilobytes=""5120"" PercentOfQuotaUsedBeforeScavenging=""50"" PercentOfQuotaUsedAfterScavenging=""20"" ExpirationPollingInterval=""00:01:00"" Name=""Isolated Storage Cache"" />
    </el:CachingSettings.Caches>
</el:CachingSettings>
</el:ConfigurationDictionary>";

var configDictionary = (IDictionary)XamlReader.Load(stringWithXAMLConfiguration);
var configSource = DictionaryConfigurationSource.FromDictionary(configDictionary);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

Or if you don't want to have the string in the code but prefer in a XAML file then ensure the XAML file's (e.g. cacheConfig.xaml) Build Action is Embedded Resource and then you can use the following code:

```
string xaml;
using (Stream s = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SilverlightApplicationCache.cacheConfig.xaml"))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        xaml = sr.ReadToEnd();

var configDictionary = (IDictionary)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
var configSource = DictionaryConfigurationSource.FromDictionary(configDictionary);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

`SilverlightApplicationCache` above is the namespace of the XAML file (eg. the default namespace of the project).